# How do I compare string letters with each other so that no letter is repeated (case insenstive) in c? It always shows some pointer error

Tags: arrays, c, loops, variable-assignment, cs50

I am new to coding(and this website) and am doing cs50 course.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    int len = strlen(argv[1]);
    if(len != 26)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(isdigit(argv[1][i]) || ispunct(argv[1][i]))
        {
            printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
            return 1;
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < len; j++)
        {
            char c = argv[1][i];
            char d = argv[1][j];
            int value = strcasecmp(&d, &c);
            if(value != 0)
            {
            printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
            return 1;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In this program, when using terminal window, the letters should not be repeated.
For example(in terminal window):-

```
./substitution qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnp
Usage: ./substitution key
```

This should be the output but it simply bypasses this check.
I also don't know when compiling the program, it asked me to add '&' before 'c' and 'd'. I would be really grateful if you explain this as well.

Comment: and what is the error????

Comment: because c and d are not strings.

Comment: The arguments to `strcasecmp()` must be null-terminated strings, not single characters. If you want to compare characters, just use `==`. If you want compare them case-insensitively, call `tolower()` to convert them to the same case: `if (tolower(c) == tolower(d))`

Comment: Using `&` just addresses the datatype problem (the arguments to the function must be `char*`), it doesn't actually make the code work. There's more to a string than just being a pointer.

Comment: You should put your `if(argc != 2)` as the _first_ statement. Otherwise, if _no_ args are specified `int len = strlen(argv[1]);` will segfault.

Comment: Your `if (strcasecmp(...) != 0` is the reverse sense of what you want (i.e. you want to abort if the two args are equal). Note that you should just use `tolower` as Barmar suggested instead. But, when `i == j`, the [corrected] test will present a false positive. I think you want: `for(int j = i + 1; j < len; j++)`.

Answer (score 0):

strcasecmp compares strings, you have characters.

you need

```
 if (tolower(c) == tolower(d))
 {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        return 1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A few issues ...

1. You have to do the `if (argc != 2)` check *before* dereferencing `argv`. Otherwise, you get a segfault.
2. You want to use `tolower` with individual chars and *not* `strcasecmp` which needs strings.
3. The code can be a lot simpler with some extra variables (e.g. a pointer to the key value).
4. When `i == j` you'll get a false positive.
5. The sense of your `if` test for duplicate is reversed.

---

Here is the refactored code. It is annotated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    // ensure we are given an argument
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key [no arg]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // point to the key string
    const char *key = argv[1];

    // get the key string length
    int len = strlen(key);

    // ensure we use all the letters
    if (len != 26) {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key [bad length]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0;  i < len;  ++i) {
        unsigned char c = key[i];

        // we want _only_ letters
        if (isdigit(c) || ispunct(c)) {
            printf("Usage: ./substitution key [digit/punct]\n");
            return 1;
        }

        // check for duplicate letters
        for (int j = i + 1;  j < len;  ++j) {
            unsigned char d = key[j];
            if (tolower(c) == tolower(d)) {
                printf("Usage: ./substitution key [duplicate '%c']\n",c);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is a version that uses `char` pointers instead of index variables:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key [no arg]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    const char *key = argv[1];

    int len = strlen(key);
    if (len != 26) {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key [bad length]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    const char *cp = key;
    for (unsigned char c = *cp++;  c != 0;  c = *cp++) {
        if (isdigit(c) || ispunct(c)) {
            printf("Usage: ./substitution key [digit/punct]\n");
            return 1;
        }

        const char *dp = cp;
        for (unsigned char d = *dp++;  d != 0;  d = *dp++) {
            if (tolower(c) == tolower(d)) {
                printf("Usage: ./substitution key [duplicate '%c']\n",c);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```